# Add dummy empty fields in CSVHelper

Tags: c#, .net, csv, export-to-csv, csvhelper

I use the library [CsvHelper](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) to write CSV. I have object which doesn't contain all the records and I have to add empty fields to my CSV. For instance:

```
public class Example
{
   public string Test1 { get; set; }
   public string Test2 { get; set; }
}
```

with this map:

```
public class ExampleMap : ClassMap<Example>
{
    public ExampleMap()
    {
      Map(ex=>ex.Test1).Index(0);
      Map(ex=>ex.Test2).Index(4);
    }
}
```

and i'd like to have for this object

```
new Example() { Test1="dummy", Test2="field" };
```

this csv result:

```
dummy;;;field
```

I really struggle with this problem, if someone can help me :)
Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: This might be superseded by the `Constant()` operator in newer versions.

A more API-consistent approach might be to use a custom `ITypeConverter`. Here is how I use it:

```
Map(i => i.SomeUnusedId).Name("SomeId").TypeConverter<EmptyConverter>(); //converst to an empty string
```

Then the converter might look like this:

```
public class EmptyConverter : ITypeConverter {
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public bool CanConvertFrom(Type type) {
        return true;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public bool CanConvertTo(Type type) {
        return true;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public object ConvertFromString(TypeConverterOptions options, string text) {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public string ConvertToString(TypeConverterOptions options, object value) {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Defining fields in the ClassMap with a constant value will allow you to define empty columns. This will generate the desired output with headers.

```
public class ExampleMap: ClassMap<Example>
{
     public ExampleMap()
     {
         Map(ex=>ex.Test1).Index(0).Name("Test1");
         Map().Index(1).Name("First Empty Column").Constant("");
         Map().Index(2).Name("Second Empty Column").Constant("");
         Map().Index(3).Name("Third Empty Column").Constant("");
         Map(ex=>ex.Test2).Index(4).Name("Test2");
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the concept of having **explicit column mappings in between** is violated.

It seems the CsvHelper library does not support such scenarios because [the library simply uses indices in ascending order](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/wiki/2.0-Changes#writer-column-sorting-done) for **defined column mappings** ("mapped columns").

But, if it is really needed to have such output, the "not-used" (reserved) columns can be introduced as follows:

```
internal sealed class Example
{
    public string Test1 { get; set; }
    public string Test2 { get; set; }

    public string Reserved1 { get; set; }
    public string Reserved2 { get; set; }
}

internal sealed class ExampleMap : CsvClassMap<Example>
{
    public ExampleMap()
    {
        Map(ex => ex.Test1).Index(0);
        Map(ex => ex.Reserved1).Index(1);
        Map(ex => ex.Reserved2).Index(2);
        Map(ex => ex.Test2).Index(3);
    }
}
```

Comment: It will be an huge waste of time for my case (I had like 100 blank fields in one of my csv) (I rewrite an old EDI which manage with blank field... !) And I tried a lot of (stupid) things (adding dummy PropertyInfo in PropertyMap, register the same dummy property...). I think about editing the core of csvhelper to solve my case ! (I had a look on your blog it is nice !)

Comment: Are there field names at the beginning of the CSV-file?

Comment: No header, just data !

Comment: It is interesting. More details on what is the input data structure (it is supposed to be not two properties?) and how the CSV-file should look like (closer to "real world") are required. P.S. Thank you! Glad you like the blog. =)

Comment: Real World structure are mixed data (date, serial numbers, encoded status and so on, and there is a lot of flux (10 files with 5 to 50 properties mapped to database on our side and to whatever on our partner side), I wrote a lot of converters which were managed dirtily in old app and look more "well handled" with csvhelper structure except for "blank fields". (Sorry for my english, it's not  my native language !)

Comment: Could you please clarify what high-level problem is being solved? Export table from SQL server to CSV file?

Comment: Yes data come mainly from database but are shaped to fit an old EDI with a partner. An other part come from our ERP and an other from filesystem. I had a look on SSIS packages but our exchange is complicated and in two way with FTP deposit and so on... !

Comment: All in all, I would like to recommend you to generate "row" and "row mapping" classes from existing SQL tables (somehow) and then use `CsvHelper` library with these "row" and "row mapping" classes. What do you think?

Comment: It won't solve my "blank field" problem. All the mapping is already  done (everything is done except solving this problem) and index are good but I can't figure how to solve this problem ! :(

Comment: It will solve the problem if there are "reserved" fields in the generated "rows" and "row mappings".

Comment: Don't know whether it can be useful, but you may try using `CsvWriter.WriteField()` and `CsvWriter.NextRecord()` methods instead of using "rows" and "row mappings". It is kind of "low-level" API.

Answer (score 0):

I finally make the choice to directly edit the final csv string for each row... It works but it's ugly !